# htaccess redirect from old to new domain name

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have an old site on a subdomain redirected with htaccess to a new domain name like this and it works fine:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} www\.subdomain\.oldsite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* http://www.newsite.com/ [R,L]
```

Because we have a lot of printed documents with links to PDFs on the old site, we need to redirect those requests to the new site under a folder (the file names stays the same).

Let me recap that; if a user request a file on the old subdomain www.subdomain.oldsite.com/file.pdf the file is now stored at www.newsite.com/folder/file.pdf

Any help to adjust my htaccess file on the old domain name is really appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

try setting this in your oldsite subdomain .htaccess

```
RewriteRule (.*\.pdf) http://www.newsite.com/folder/$1 [R=301,L]
```

**edit:**
tested, and works